# Maven parent POM vs BOM dependency management

Tags: maven, pom.xml, dependency-management, maven-bom

Let's say I have a maven parent POM `root` which defines `foo:bar:1.0.0` in dependency management. I have another parent POM `parent` which uses `root` as parent (just to add another layer to the example). Lastly I have a bill of materials `bom` which uses `root` as its parent but redefines `foo:bar:2.0.0` in its dependency management.

In my project `app` I inherit from `parent` and then I [import the BOM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) in the dependency management section of `app`

```
root (foo:bar:1.0.0) <- parent <- app+bom
 ^
 |
bom (foo:bar:2.0.0)
```

Which dependency management section wins? Which version of `foo:bar` do I get?

I know that if I were to directly include `foo:bar` in the dependency management section of `app`, it would override that inherited from the parent. But is *importing* a BOM in the dependency management section equivalent to directly including it in the dependency management section, and sufficient to override that of the parent? Or does the inherited `foo:bar` from the parent's dependency management take precedence?

Comment: Closest to the project I think.

Comment: Importing a bom is _not_ the same as putting them in the dependencyManagement directly, but weaker. I never found a document specifying the precedence and I just have a vague understanding through examples.

Comment: If you are unsure about which dependencies in what versions get pulled into your project, you could try `mvn dependency:tree` or `mvn help:effective-pom`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the maven precedence rules, the version from the root will win and therefore you will get foo:bar:1.0.0, which you will be able to see if you look at the effective POM. I think that this makes a BOM project less effective since you cannot use it to override the version from the parent and have to declare the version in the app or in the parent.

> **The Precedence**
>
> So, there are multiple ways of deciding the versions,
> which means there is an order of precedence.
>
> - Versions provided in the direct declaration in POM take the highest precedence.
> - Version provided in parent pom takes second precedence.
> - Version from imported pom takes third place
> - Lastly, whatever we get from dependency mediation

Comment: "According to the maven precedence rules …" Can you provide an authoritative reference?

Comment: I found this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-maven-bom also the section on importing BOM on maven's site https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies but the precendence is only hinted at.

Comment: Well, it looks to be true in practice, just had a weird case and went to confirm. This is how it behaves - in my case imported pom is after parent pom and someone changed the parent pom...

Comment: I wish there were an authoritative reference, but since multiple people are reporting that this is indeed how it works, I'll go ahead and mark this as the correct answer.